# Can't load file with <input type="file"> ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="file" asp-for="Image" class="form-control">
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

The image exists correctly in the class controller.

When I selected, for example, image, my program crashed. I think it's maybe related with configuration or some packages, because I have other project and there everything is going fine. In scripts I don't see any difference.

Comment: "My program crashed" is not helpful. What error do you get? What are you trying to so  with the uploaded file on the server side?

Comment: On the client side when i select file, program ended with "has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)"

Comment: Is your problem solved ?  " The image exists correctly in the class controller." where do you select the file ? From local folder ? Or ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Image property in your model has the [FromForm] attribute in your controller action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult TuAccion([FromForm] TuModelo modelo)
    {
        // Tu lógica de procesamiento aquí
        return RedirectToAction("AlgunaAccion");

}
```

In your Startup.cs file, verify that the service configuration includes middleware for handling files:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Otras configuraciones

    services.AddMvc();
    
    // Agrega soporte para cargar archivos
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

Ensure that these configurations are set up correctly to handle file uploads in your ASP.NET Core application.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure Image property in your model (TuModelo) is type of "IFormFile" (in asp.net core), older versions of .net, it should be type of "HttpPostedFileBase"